# Mocking success method on jQuery ajax call is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, mocking, qunit

#### Problem

I'm using QUnit, and following this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522437/qunit-parameterized-tests-and-mocking) which seems to work in that scenario.

The data I attempt to supply to the 'success' method doesn't 'arrive' - it's not in the format required, or comes through as undefined. I can't see where I'm going wrong.

#### Walk-through

The '*unitTest*' method that supplies my '*methodUnderTest*' with a DOM element. The '*methodUnderTest*' makes an jQuery ajax call, which is *mocked* in the unit test. Then success is called, and the result of the success method executing forms the unit test assert.

#### Code

I have set this up as a **[JSFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/NickJosevski/2mbWq/18/)**, if you would like to see the code executing (failing to execute as expected). But here is some of it, in case my mistake is very obvious:

```
//stubbing the ajax call
jQuery.ajax = function (param) {
    options = param;
};

//the data
var expectedData = jQuery.parseJSON({
        'id': 'fbs',
        'fieldName': 'fbs',
        'data': 'fbs-text'
    });

//call to success method, in unit test
options.success({
    sdata: expectedData,
    textStatus: 'is-this-data-arriving',
    jqXhr: 123
});

//the success method that is failing to get the expected data
function handleSuccess (sdata, textStatus, jqXhr) {
    //problem is here not this success method never gets the data
    console.log('sdata: ' + sdata + '|textStatus:' + textStatus + '|jq:' + jqXhr);
    jQuery('#' + sdata.fieldName + '-loading').attr('alt', 'modified');
};
```

Comment: you can give mockjax a try, i use it along qunit and sinonjs for a full testing js suite http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/07/mock-your-ajax-requests-with-mockjax-for-rapid-development/

Comment: @Poelinca Dorin, Thanks I did try it and have 2 working solutions now. I did get the other way working too.

Comment: nice to hear that, i still recomend you have a look at sinonjs if you're into testing

Comment: @PoelincaDorin looks interesting. Added it to my daily task list.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there was a few mistakes that were interfering with each other. This was a pretty localized issue, but with the working code here now if someone reaches a similar problem hopefully this will be helpful.

#### Working solution

> http://jsfiddle.net/NickJosevski/9ZZmc/4/

#### Correct Code Snippets

```
//1.
//making the parseJSON method work correctly by supplying a single string
//as per http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

var jsonText = '{"id": "fbs", "fieldName": "fbs", "data": "fbs-text" }'),
    expectedData = $.parseJSON(jsonText);

//2.
//passing the values to the success method correctly
var ignoreParamForThisDemo = null;
options.success(expectedData, ignoreParamForThisDemo , ignoreParamForThisDemo );

//3.
//Other minor issues (broken assert logic) that can be seen in the final solution
```

Comment: If you need more context/code examples, I've blogged more info here - http://blog.nick.josevski.com/2012/01/05/unit-testing-javascript-methods-that-contain-jquery-ajax-calls/